# Parametrization of a surface of revolution

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

My question is how to show that the following map is a parametrization:

$$
X(u, v) = x(u) a + y(u) \cos v b - y(u) \sin v c, \qquad (u, v) \in I \times (\theta, \theta + 2 \pi) 
$$

where $\{a, b, c\}$ is a positively oriented orthonormal basis or the 3-space, $I$ is an open interval of the real line and $x, y: I \longrightarrow \Bbb{R}$ are functions that do not take the zero value for the same $t \in I$.

This is, according to the solution of Exercise (3) of chapter 2 of *Curves and Surfaces*, 2nd Edition, by Montiel and Ros, a parametrization of a surface of revolution around an axis $R$ in the direction of $a$.

I can see, intuitively, that $X$ is an homeomorphism, but I am failing to write a formal proof. Also, I computed the derivative
$$
(dX)_{(u, v)} = \begin{bmatrix} 
x'(u) & 0 \\
y'(u) \cos v & - y(u) \sin v \\
- y'(u) \sin v & - y(u) \cos v
\end{bmatrix}
$$
but I am unable to show that it is injective.

Any help will be the most appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

With the hints by Ted Shifrin I was able to show that the derivative is injective:

Let $(z, w) \in \Bbb{R}^2$. We will show that we cannot have $(dX)_{(u, v)}(z, w) = 0$ unless $(z, w) = 0$. Indeed, if it was the case, we would have
\begin{align*}
& x'(u)z = 0, \\
& y'(u) \cos v z - y(u) \sin v w = 0, \\
& - y'(u) \sin v z - y(u) \cos v w = 0.
\end{align*} 
If $z = 0$ then $w = 0$. Suppose that $x'(u) = 0$ and $z \neq 0$. Then $y'(u) \neq 0$. If $\cos v = 0$ or $\sin v = 0$ then $z = w = 0$. If not, then 
$$
w = \frac{y'(u)}{y(u)} \frac{1}{\tan v}z = - \frac{y'(u)}{y(u)} \tan v z \implies z = - \tan^2 v z \implies z = w = 0.
$$

I am yet unable to find an inverse function for $X(u, v)$.

Comment: The correct hypothesis should be that $y(u)$ is never zero. If the distance from the axis of revolution becomes $0$, the surface generally develops singularities. Of course, one also needs $x'(u)^2+y'(u)^2$ everywhere nonzero.

Comment: Dear @TedShifrin, thank you very much. Indeed, the condition of $x$ and $y$ not being zero simultaneously was on my account, I had made a wrong picture of the situation. Now, what about the condition on the derivatives: what does it mean, and why do we need it?

Comment: The curve $(x(u),y(u))$ is the curve that you rotate to make the surface. You want it to be a regular curve. That means that its velocity is never the $0$ vector.

Comment: By the way, if I haven't mentioned it, you might find my text on curves and surfaces helpful. Free, linked in my profile.

Comment: I got your first comment, any thanks. Indeed you have, I take a look at it sometimes, but I have some difficulty with reading on the computer. I am using a printed copy of Montiel and Ros, and at times give a look at your book and also Manfredo's.